# Synchronize to posedge of clock

Tags: system-verilog

Is there any way to interrogate whether the simulation is at the `@(posedge clk)` event aside from using a named event that's triggered at the same time?

With the following code, I can make sure that I only do stuff at the posedge of a clock:

```
module tb;

  bit clk;
  always #2 clk = ~clk;

  event pos_clk;


  always @(posedge clk)
    -> pos_clk;

  initial begin
    // stuff happens
    @(posedge clk);
    $display("[%0d] @(posedge clk)", $time());

    // control is passed asynchronously to some task
    // - since it's already at a posedge, it doesn't need to wait
    some_task();

    // other stuff happens
    #1;
    $display("[%0d] #1", $time());

    // control is passed asynchronously to some task
    // - since it's not at a posedge, it needs to catch the next one
    some_task();

    $finish();
  end

  task some_task();
    wait (pos_clk.triggered);
    $display("[%0d] wait (pos_clk.triggered)", $time());
    // do relevant stuff
  endtask
endmodule
```

Is there some other way I could do this without the extra named event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `##0` construct does (See section *14.11 Cycle delay: ##* of the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)). You do have to define a default clocking block, which means your task has to be defined inside a `module` or `interface`

```
module tb;

  bit clk;
  always #2 clk = ~clk;

  default clocking cb @(posedge clk)
  endclocking

  initial begin
    // stuff happens
    @(cb) // when using clocking blocks, only use the clocking event
    $display("[%0d] @(posedge clk)", $time());

    // control is passed asynchronously to some task
    // - since it's already at a posedge, it doesn't need to wait
    some_task();

    // other stuff happens
    #1;
    $display("[%0d] #1", $time());

    // control is passed asynchronously to some task
    // - since it's not at a posedge, it needs to catch the next one
    some_task();

    $finish();
  end

  task some_task();
    ##0;
    $display("[%0d] wait (pos_clk.triggered)", $time());
    // do relevant stuff
  endtask
endmodule
```

My advice would be not to do either and figure out a way to keep the activation of `some_task` synchronous.

Comment: I want to do the synchronization inside a class, so a default clocking won't work. What I basically wanted was to make a driver get an item only at a posedge. I noticed problems when running virtual sequences that work on multiple clocks. I guess the only option then is to do something like : wait for clock, check if item available, if not, go on, if so, start driving. This is kind of against the whole TLM philosophy of being transaction driven (i.e. using get_next_item()), but at the same time, the driver lives in both worlds (RTL and TLM) and has to reconcile both aspects.

Comment: Also, even if I do make `some_task()` synchronously triggered, I might want to write a program assertion to check this pre-condition (that execution has indeed started at a posedge).

Comment: I still think its a bad practice to mix sync and async behavior in the same procedure. But I don't think you have any other choice other than what you originally posted.